# Fortran: Pure subroutine of moving in the text of a group of lines from the First line to the Last line after the K-th line

Tags: recursion, fortran

The task is performed in the form of a software project of two modules, in which it is necessary to use unidirectional lists of unknown length in advance.

Task:
Develop a clean routine for moving in the text a group of lines from the First line to the Last line after the K-th line. The values of First, Last, K are set in the second input file. The correct data is the situation when First≤Last, and K does not belong to the interval [First, Last].
Indication The list item is a string.

I did input, output, and retrieve an item from a list. But I can’t understand how to rearrange sentences in the text according to the conditions of the problem.

Code on github: [enter link description here](https://github.com/JubasNTC/fortran-labs/tree/master/labs/2)

source_process.f90

```
module Source_Process
   use Environment
   use Source_IO

   implicit none

contains
   recursive function get_element(current_element, number) result(element)
      type(SourceLine), pointer, intent(in)  :: current_element
      type(SourceLine), pointer :: element
      integer, intent(in) :: number

      element => null()
      if (associated(current_element)) then
         if (number == 0) then
            element => current_element
         else
            element => get_element(current_element%next, number - 1)
         end if
      end if
   end function get_element
end module Source_process
```

Thanks in advance for your reply.

Comment: If you want to be a bit more flashy an array of derived type which contains a character var of allocatable length (or an allocatable array of char of length 1) (sorry if this is what you mean by an array of strings), and have 1 per line. Don't even need to read twice, read once and realloc each time you read a line. And then you can reorder lines easily with an array.

Comment: Problem Solved.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
module Source_Process
   use Environment
   use Source_IO

   implicit none

contains
   subroutine Move_Strings(NB, KB, K, InitialStrings)    
      type(SourceLine), pointer, intent(inout)  :: InitialStrings
      integer, intent (in)                      :: NB, KB, K

      type(SourceLine), pointer  :: CurrentInitial, CurrentTmp
      type(SourceLine), pointer  :: CurrentK, CurrentNB, PrevNB, CurrentKB

      integer                    ::  number_string = 1

      CurrentInitial => InitialStrings

      CurrentK  => null()
      CurrentNB => null()
      CurrentKB => null()

      do while (Associated(CurrentInitial))
         if (number_string == K) then
            CurrentK => CurrentInitial
         else if (number_string == NB - 1) then
            PrevNB => CurrentInitial
         else if (number_string == NB) then
            CurrentNB => CurrentInitial
         else if (number_string == KB) then
            CurrentKB => CurrentInitial
         end if
         CurrentInitial => CurrentInitial%Next
         number_string = number_string + 1
      end do

      if (NB == 1) then
         InitialStrings => CurrentKB%next
      else
         PrevNB%next => CurrentKB%next
      end if

      CurrentKB%next => CurrentK%next
      CurrentK%next => CurrentNB

   end subroutine Move_Strings
end module Source_process
```

Problem Solved.

Comment: I am confused. Is this an answer with a solution or update of the problem? If an update, it should be an edit of the question. If an answer, there should be some more explanation.

Comment: Then it should probably rather be an update to your question (using the edit button) so that it i clear you do not have a solution yet.

Comment: Problem Solved.

Comment: Some explanation would be helpful.